# Adding scripting code in web.config file gives 500 error on live site

Tags: c#, asp.net, scripting, web-config

I am implementing some functionality which pulls data through the scripting code which is below:-

```
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="300000"/>
  </webServices>
</scripting>  </system.web.extensions>
```

I add the above code in the `web.config` but it gives me error as

> 500 Internal server error.

However it works fine on my `local server`. I have no idea what wrong is happening.

Comment: You haven't actually shown your code. Just some configuration settings. We need to see the actual code, see the URL you're calling, and you need to check the server event logs to see what the error is. We can't help you until you've done that.

Comment: @mason: The code works fine and the config file is giving me error, When I remove the above code. The page runs fine.

Comment: So it sounds like you've found your solution. Remove the configuration and your site works. Problem solved right? Unless there's something you failed to mention in your question.

Comment: it is probably wrong cofiguration on the iis for the live site, check my answer and see if it helps.

Comment: @mybirthname: trying that only..

Comment: okay if you think it is wrong, good luck with your problem.

Comment: @mybirthname: i said the steps are incorrect. i m still trying your option

Comment: @mybirthname: I did not downvoted your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the Issue cleared. It was just the framework issue.

I changed as described by the [My birth name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2147652/mybirthname) i changed the IIS settings accordingly and it worked fine.

**STEPS**

- Open IIS.
- Right Click on the Site/Virtual Dir. Select PROPERTIES
- Select the Asp.Net Tab
- Select the .Net version from the dropdown.
- Click SAVE

I changed the Framework from `v2.0` to `v4.0`

Comment: You need to say *what* you changed in order to have a valid answer. Saying "I fixed it" helps nobody else that stumbles across your question.

Comment: You need to say what version of .NET you were previously on, and what you changed it to.

Comment: If you configure application pool only for your solution, my steps are correct. They are different ways to fix it. Hope I helped you, good luck !

Comment: @mybirthname: yes your solution gave me hint. but you deleted your answer. No worries, I resolved it though :)